# How to calculate the values of each region for a 4-way venn diagram using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, venn-diagram

I have 4 columns (A,B,C,D) each with data in a combination of text, number and character.

eg: R.E(-18.01)AEEPSAFMTRL(-.98).R

The four columns contain such strings, some of which are present in only one column, some in 2, some in 3 and some in all 4 with all possible combinations. Also the size of the columns is different.

I need to construct a 4 way venn diagram which can give me all possible combination values.

I don't need to construct the venn figure, I just need the values using MATLAB

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the intersection between a given column of data X and another Y, where X or Y could even be the intersection between another pair of columns.

Let Z be the intersection of columns X and Y. The column vector Z in Matlab is `Z = X( any( bsxfun( @eq, X, Y' ), 2) );`

This is a short script that would compare the first intersection between A, B, C, and D, but I leave the rest to you.

```
% Intersection function
f = @(X,Y) X( any( bsxfun( @eq, X, Y' ), 2) );
% Matrix M of all columns, built however you have it
M = zeros( max([size(A,1),size(B,1),size(C,1),size(D,1)]), 4);
M(1:size(A,1),1) = A; M(1:size(B,1),2) = B; 
M(1:size(C,1),3) = C; M(1:size(D,1),4) = D;
M( M==0 ) = nan; % Empty space in M is nan, which won't trigger as equal
k = 1; 
% Compares and stores AB, AC, AD, BC, ... 
for i = 1 : (size(M,2)-1)
    for j = (i+1) : size(M,2)
        n = numel( f( M(:,i), M(:,j) ) );
        N( 1:n, k ) = f( M(:,i), M(:,j) ); k=k+1;
    end
end
```